# SQL Query - Sum at higher level for the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have data in a SQL Server database and this query gives me the top table

```
SELECT date, resource_name, transfer_resource_name, SUM(calls) as calls 
FROM abc
```

I could not figure out on how to populate the `total_calls` column as shown in the bottom table from the picture. Basically, I need to sum the calls and group by select date, resource_name as for total_calls column.

Any inputs will be appreciated!

[Here is a picture of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydCPT.png)

Comment: How about first grouping by `Resource_Name` and then joining the result on the original table to select all together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query will not work in SQL Server, so I presume that the actual query has a `group by`.

Then you can do what you want using window functions:

```
SELECT date, resource_name, transfer_resource_name, SUM(calls) as calls,
       SUM(SUM(calls)) OVER (PARTITION BY resource_name) as total_calls 
FROM abc
GROUP BY date, resource_name, transfer_resource_name;
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It needs to have a group by. This is exactly what I need. Thanks Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

use a subquery.

```
SELECT 
    O.date, 
    O.resource_name, 
    O.transfer_resource_name, 
    SUM(O.calls) as calls,
    (
        SELECT  SUM(I.calls)
        FROM    abc I
        WHERE   I.resource_name = O.resource_name
    ) total_calls    
FROM abc O
```

Comment: I will try this as well, thank you for your help Sam.

Comment: @Mixer, Gordon's answer is better, so unless you have any issues with it, go with his. My answer is generic SQL but if you're SQL Server specific (which you said you are) then use `PARTITION BY`.